# Можно ли в php получить весь запрос, который я отправил (вместе с заголовком) ?

Tags: php, http

Много искал, но так и не нашел что-то подобное. Можно вывести всевозможные переменные, но никак не получилось вернуть полный запрос.

Можно ли это добиться средствами php не прибегая к помощи снифера?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`print_r($_REQUEST);` - выведет $_GET, $_POST, $_COOKIE
http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.request.php

`$headers = GetAllHeaders();  
foreach($headers as $header=>$value)  
echo "$header: $value<br>";` - выведет заголовки
http://www.spravkaweb.ru/php/managfun/www/headerquery